# How to calculate the density of a datetime variable? r

Tags: r, probability-density

Currently I'm converting the datetime variable using as.numeric. But my density estimates are too low.

```
tenevents$datetime <- c("2016-01-18 07:00:00 EST", "2016-02-15 11:00:00 EST", "2016-02-25 12:00:00 EST", "2016-03-01 11:00:00 EST", "2016-03-12 09:00:00 EST", "2016-05-19 16:46:00 EDT", "2016-09-13 09:30:00 EDT","2016-09-15 07:15:00 EDT", "2016-10-03 10:26:00 EDT", "2016-11-19 04:00:00 EST")

v <- density( as.numeric(tenevents$datetime), bw = ucv(as.numeric(tenevents$datetime)) )
```

Is it important to scale variables before doing density estimates? Is as.numeric() the best approach?

Comment: Why are you worried about the scale of a density estimate? It integrates to 1. If you want really high density values, divide your data by `1e9`. Only the shape matters. Your x-axis is seconds, so you could use `x/60^2` to convert to hours, or  `x/60^2/24/7` to do weeks.

Comment: @Gregor I'm using the estimate on a division. Like in page 6 of [Mohler](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~frederic/papers/crime1.pdf).

Comment: Think about units. When you use `as.numeric` on a POSIX datetime, you get seconds. Convert that to whatever unit is meaningful for you and consistent with whatever other measures you are using.